# adding array values to jquery graph syntax

Tags: php, jquery, json, each

I have a an array that has been json encoded from php

The array looks like this(called $jsonGraphData;):

```
[{"Type":"Category","Name":"games","TotalClicks":"162"},{"Type":"Category","Name":"apps","TotalClicks":"29"},{"Type":"Category","Name":"music","TotalClicks":"28"},{"Type":"Category","Name":"video","TotalClicks":"25"}]
```

I would like to use the array values in a loop within a jquery function that generates a graph. These are the hard coded values that allows the graph to work:

```
series: [{
                name: 'games',
                data: [162]

            }, {
                name: 'apps',
                data: [29]

            }, {
                name: 'video',
                data: [25]

            }]
```

What I would like to do is to use jquery 'each' to loop through the array so that defining the series is dynamic this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var totalClicks = $jsonGraphData; (this is the array, the alert works fine).

series: [{
  $.each(totalClicks, function(index, val) {
    alert('name: ' + val.Name + ' ' + 'data: ' + val.TotalClicks);
    //here is where I need the format to be the same as the example above.
  });   
}]
```

I lack the knowledge of jquery syntax to achieve this and do not know what to search for on Google.

Comment: So how does the first array map to the second one? what should be in data and what should not ?

Comment: @ryadavilli. I am not to sure what you mean by map (I am still new at this).  The array Name and Data will be relevant to each other.  So the output of the alert is "name: London, data: [124]". I just need to be able to tell the script that.

Comment: My Question is your inital map contains games and total clicks, and your second map contaisn data as an array. Can you at least explain where should games go, and where should total clicks go?

Comment: @ryadavilli  Ah, I see.  I only need 1 integer value in 'data' not an array. I will update the sample code to be more precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var series = [];
  $.each(totalClicks, function(index, val) {
    series.push({name: val.Name, data: val.TotalClicks});
  });
```

Or if data should still be an array with only one value in it.

```
var totalClicks = [{ "Type": "Category", "Name": "games", "TotalClicks": "162" }, { "Type": "Category", "Name": "apps", "TotalClicks": "29" }, { "Type": "Category", "Name": "music", "TotalClicks": "28" }, { "Type": "Category", "Name": "video", "TotalClicks": "25"}]

var series = [];
$(totalClicks).each(function (index, val) {
    series.push({ "name": val.Name, "data": [val.TotalClicks] });
});
```

Comment: Mmmm, this seems to be what I need, but I am getting an error on the console: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) '  I am just checking to see if I messed up.

Comment: Edited my code above (the second version) to include a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery for looping through the regular array.

```
for(var obj in yourArray){
  // do whatever you need with it.
  alert(obj.Name + " " + obj.TotalClicks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is more that I don't know the query equivalent of 'echo' to get the array values into the loop.  I can get the alert to work.

Comment: Do you need to display the values in the html document? if so you can use:

$('yourElementSelector').html(obj.Name + " " + obj.TotalClicks)

Comment: I need to use the values in the header section of the document as part of another jquery script. there are no selectors, which is where I am stuck.